# How do I figure out distinct elements from part of an array?

Tags: arrays, ruby, unique, distinct

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  I have an array that has values like this

```
['1/ 8', '5 / 16', nil, '12 / 25', nil, '8/9']
```

My question is, when the element in the array is not `nil`, how do I figure out all the unique values that come after the `"/"`?  You can assume that all the values in the array are either `nil` or have a `"/"` followed by some degree of white space, and then a number.

Comment: Also, as a piece of advice, it looks like you are working with fractions. You might want to use Ruby's rational type for this. You can read more [here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Rational.html).

Comment: What have you tried already? It is easier to understand a question and help when you post what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get your question correctly and you need to get `8` (or `'8'`?) out from `'1/ 8'`:

```
a = ['1/ 8', '5 / 16', nil, '12 / 25', nil, '8/9']
a.compact.each_with_object({}) do |str, hash|
  hash[str] = str.split('/').last.split(' ').map(&:to_i).uniq
end
#=> {"1/ 8"=>[8], "5 / 16"=>[16], "12 / 25"=>[25], "8/9"=>[9]}
```

If you need to get only uniq values:

```
values = a.compact.flat_map {|str| str.split('/').last.split(' ').map(&:to_i) }.uniq
#=> [8, 16, 25, 9]
```

Comment: HI, Thanks.  Where are the unique values stored?  When I run 'puts "#{a}"', its printing out the array as if it were unchanged.

Comment: Nice.  The expression "values = a.compact.flat_map {|str| str.split('/').last.split(' ').map(&:to_i).uniq }" actually returns non-unique items (e.g. [24, 40, 24, 40]) but when I ran values.uniq afterwards it returned an array of only unique values.

Comment: @Natalia you did not say you needed the resulting array to be uniq, you only mentioned you need the uniq numbers of a string after `/` :) But good you found what you needed (I edited the answer though)

Comment: The question refers to the "the unique values that come after the '/', not the unique numbers. Taken literally they are unique strings, but the asker may intend "values" to be interpreted as numbers. Natalia, you need to be precise in your wording, not just in SO questions, but more generally in all your coding work.

Answer (score 0):

Using Eli's suggestion to use the rational type:

```
a.compact.map{|f| f.delete(' ').to_r}.map(&:denominator).uniq
```

Edit: Note that this is based on the assumption that these are fractions (and therefore the `to_r` would apply).

Comment: nice one! but will fail if what we see in OP is a coincidence of similarity to rationals, and there are examples of `"1 /2 3"` (it will return `23` in stead of `2`, `3`). But, after all, I have no idea what OP wants here exactly, so.. ;p

Comment: @AndreyDeineko You are correct, and that was an assumption in the comment I based my answer on. I should probably have mentioned it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
arr.map { |str| str && str[%r{/(.*)}, 1].to_i }
# => [8, 16, nil, 25, nil, 9]
```

How does this work?

- `map` is a loop that collects its results into a new array
- `str && ...` executes the latter part if `str` is not nil
- `str[regexp, 1]` matches a regexp and returns the 1st capture group
- `%r{/(.*)}` is a regexp that matches everything after the slash

Answer (score 0):

I have interpreted the question literally.

```
arr = ['1/ 8', 'dog/ 25', nil, '12 / 25', nil, '8/9', '1/2 5', '1 / cat', '2/', '3 4']

arr.map { |obj| obj.to_s[/(?<=\/).*/] }.compact.uniq
  #=> [" 8", " 25", "9", "2 5", " cat", ""]
```

The regex matches all characters following a forward slash, the forward slash being matched in a positive lookbehind.

Note `nil.to_s #=> ''`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're working with Rationals, so you could use [`Rational`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/Rational.html) :

```
array = ['1/ 8', '5 / 16', nil, '12 / 25', nil, '8/9']

rationals = array.compact.map do |string|
  Rational(string.delete(' '))
end
#=> [(1/8), (5/16), (12/25), (8/9)]

unique_denominators = rationals.map(&:denominator).uniq
#=> [8, 16, 25, 9]
```

Note that the Rationals are irreducible :

You'll get `[3]` as unique denominator for `['4/ 6', '1 / 3']`, which depending on your needs, might be a feature or a bug.